# Apache to Nginx rewrite for non assets matching a substring

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have the following Apache rewrite condition and just cannot figure out what the correct way is to convert it to an Nginx rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(site|search|members|P[0-9]{2,8}) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Edit:
It turns out that a rule down the page was hijacking my previous rules.
The problematic rule was this one:

```
if (!-d $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine two REQUEST_URI conditions into one regexp, and use it as location specifier. Then inside location you check for file existence.

```
location ~ ^\/(site|search|members|P[0-9]{2,8})(?!(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}$)) {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 break;
    }
    # here goes something like 'root ..' for getting existent file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
# nginx configuration
location ~ "(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$" {
}
location / {
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 break;
}
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks!  This is a good answer based on the fact that it separates out locations (as is the nginx way),